# MathJax with RequireJS, how to set config

Tags: requirejs, mathjax

Usually, I can include MathJax in a script tag like:

```
<script src="path-to-MathJax/MathJax.js?config=default"></script>
```

But with RequireJS, I can include the config, but what happens to the config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirejs documentation on github mentions that you can gain fine-grained control on the URL, by overriding the requirejs load function:
https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Fine-grained-URL-control

```
<script src="require.js"></script>
<script>
(function () {
  var load = requirejs.load;
  requirejs.load = function (context, moduleId, url) {
    //modify url here, then call original load
    return load(context, moduleId, url);
  };

  //Now load code.
  require(['main']);
}());
</script>
```

Comment: For completeness. It is possible to specify a urlArgs parameter in the config -- http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-urlArgs. However, it will be added to ALL files. It is meant to be used for cache busting. Not for a one off.

Answer (score 5):

It's now explained in  the Mathjax documentation :

https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-docs/wiki/Integrating-mathjax-into-x%3A-require.js

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal as you would loose the ability to load it only when required. If nothing else works, you can always use this approach as last resort.

Instead of loading MathJax from within require, load it as a script.

Instead of:

```
<script data-main="main" src="libs/require.js"></script>
```

Try this:

```
<script src="libs/require.js"></script>
<script src="path-to-MathJax/MathJax.js?config=default"></script>
<script>require(["main"]);</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also load `require.js` and do

```
<script>require(["path-to-MathJax/MathJax.js?config=default"]);</script>
```